# Define Color From Video in Real Time

Tags: flutter, dart

I use AudioPlayer in Flutter for web videos. I have some backgrounded videos. But the color of background changes when the render time. I am definitely sure about normal video background color and my flutter background color is same .

[image]

In this situation how can I detect the first pixels on Video in real time. Or how can I filter video ?

Comment: `I am definitely sure about normal video background color and my flutter background color is same` - could you please provide your video, and provide your flutter code (showing how you use video and color widgets)

Comment: @ch271828n this is original video https://smoody.app/video/rocket.mp4 . I am just wrap with Container with color: Color(0XffBLABLABLA)

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue previously. What I did on my approach was extract the popular color from the video image thumbnail instead of updating the background based on the current frame (seems inefficient).

I used the [image_pixels](https://pub.dev/packages/image_pixels) plugin to fetch the popular color on the image and with `ImagePixels.container`, the background is automatically filled with the popular color.

```dart
ImagePixels.container(
  /// Let _imageSource be the video thumbnail
  imageProvider: _imageSource,
  child: Container(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child: SizedBox(
      width: _imageWidth, 
      /// You can add the video player inside SizedBox
      /// or whichever preferred Widget 
      child: Image(image: _imageSource)),
  ),
),
```